# Logarithm inequality - Is it possible?

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to solve the following inequality:

$$n^2 > 2n^{\log_2 (3)} + 1$$

My final result is:

$$-\frac{1}{2} > n^{\log_2(3) -2}$$

with $n > 1$.

*Do you think that this operation is possible? If it is, can you show me the solution?*

Answer (score 1):

No, your attempt is incorrect.

What you can do is to consider the function
$$
f(x)=x^2-2x^\alpha+1
$$
(where $\alpha=\log_23$, for simplicity) and study where it's positive.

Let's limit ourselves to the interval $[1,\infty)$. We have $f(1)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$. Next
$$
f'(x)=2x-2\alpha x^{\alpha-1}=2x^{\alpha-1}(x^{2-\alpha}-\alpha)
$$
which is positive for $x^{2-\alpha}>\alpha$. The only possible point where it vanishes is where $x^{2-\alpha}=\alpha$.

Note that $g(x)=x^{2-\alpha}-\alpha$ has $g(1)=1-\alpha<0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$, because $1<\alpha<2$. Since $g$ is increasing, there is exactly one point where the derivative vanishes
and where $f$ has a minimum (necessarily negative).

Since $f(4)=-1$ and $f(5)\approx0.36$, we see that your inequality is satisfied for the integers $n>4$.

Comment: Thanks. that's a much more likable answer than the other

Comment: But I know that 6 is minimum positive integer where 2n^log2(3) -1 is lower than n^2. I've confirmed it by replacing n with the number. so that n=6, n^2 = 36 and  2n^log2(3) -1 = 35

Comment: @InêsBarataFeioBorges I checked my computations and found the same result.